# How to configure the rootURL for the production environment?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'd like to host an Ember app in the `/blog/` directory. I found the following code in the documentation to make that happen but I have trouble to make it work.

```
App.Router.reopen({
  rootURL: '/blog/'
});
```

At what position do I have to include this code or is there a better way to do it anyway? I'd like to fire up `ember build --environment=production` and than copy `/dist/*` to the `/blog/` directory on the webserver.

Comment: Please, describe what troubles do you have. Errors, blank page, something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that, you should set `baseURL` in `config/environment.js`:

```
if (environment === 'production') {
  ENV.baseURL = '/blog/';
}
```

Also, if you encounter any issues with hash location setup or IE9 you could also use following code in `app/router.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

let Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.baseURL
});
```

Comment: baseUrl deprecated https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2016/04/28/baseURL.html